# Compile custom module for Kivy-ios

Tags: python, ios, xcode, python-requests, kivy

I finally have some idea how to build Kivy app in Xcode with help of Kivy-ios. But Xcode and mac environment is new to me. My issue is: how to compile other python modules that required for my application. There is 'build-all.sh' in 'kivy-ios/tools' that builds standard things, but how to add some other module. In particular, I need Requests module. Maybe there's some template script to include custom python modules? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how kivy-ios manages different modules, but in the absence of anything else you can simply copy the requests module into your app dir so it's included along with everything else.

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that. Thanks a lot!